# Use of 'à peine' in a sentence?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, adverbes

I was wondering if I have used the adverb 'à peine' correctly.

> "Le weekend a passé tellement vite que j'ai l'impression d'avoir à peine eu un moment de repos."

Translation:

> The weekend went by so fast that I feel like I hardly got a moment to relax.

I'm not sure whether the adverb should go after the first or second conjugated verb.

Comment: Je does not follow the first person personal pronoun rule of English (I always; Je in the beginning of a sentence only).

Comment: perfect, don't fret about it

Answer (score 1):

**A**_ This adverbial  locution does not seem quite proper in this context, but this elusive feeling  can be explained to a certain extent. The reason is that it is used to **express a judgement relative to a point on a given scale** and that the scale that is implied is not usual (but in principle not unreal).

- **time**_  à peine 5 heure (it is not yet the time for going to bed)
- **size**_  à peine 5 kilogrammes (it big for a turkey, but not too big)
- **age**_  à peine quarante ans (that is not enough to call her old)
- **vitesse**_ à peine à cinquante à l'heure (ils n'ont pas pu avoir un accident grave à cette vitesse)

You can apply it to "a while's rest" as you can consider "a while's rest" as a point on a scale (although not as nice a scale as those above) -- it'll have to be the scale of the possible durations of a resting period --

- **possible durations of a resting period**_ à peine un moment de repos

**B**_ The place of the locution is without contest correct if right before what it modifies.

- J'ai l'impression qu'il lui a été donné **à peine** une légère punition.

These next possibilities of placing it among the parts of the verb seem equally likely but they are objectionable as adverbs and adverbial locutions are modifiers of **nouns**, **adjectives**, and **verbs**.

- Je crois qu'il a fini à peine son dessert.  (He finished his dessert but not much of anything else.)
- Je crois qu'il a à peine fini son dessert. (He's just finished his dessert.)

Comment: “Il a fini à peine son dessert” is weird (I didn't understand what you meant first). A better example would be “Il en est à peine à l'entrée”.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez « De tout les plats qui ont été servis il a fini à peine le dessert. Oh non! Il me semble qu'il a fini tous les plat et il a même repris du premier. » (seulement)  It is such a context that I refer to; however, I do have some doubts, even more so as I see that you do have some too. It is nevetheless bizarre that if « seulement » is used as a replacement, which is most often possible, then that strangeness feeling disappears.

Comment: “À peine” means “just now”/“only now” in these examples (in other cases it can mean “hardly”), but you try to confer them with the meaning of “only [something]”. That's also probably why I don't agree with the statement that the use in the OP's sentence is improper. It sounds natural to me.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez The OP says in his/her question that he/she is not sure (wondering) and so as I understand this feeling I say along with him  that it does not **seem** to be proper but I add that it is only an impression and that I think my explanation can help to dissipate it. I do not assert that it should be improper. As regards the meaning "just now" I think it is not the one that applies here : à peine eu un moment de repos: n'avoir eu pas plus qu'un moment de repos, seulement un moment de repos alors que cela aurait pu être un jour complet ou même deux.